# Setting visibility of ProgressBar before and after emitting value from an observable

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I've an RxJava observable in my android application which emits items brought from server and repeats like this:

```
Observable.interval(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<Something>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Something> call(Long aLong) {
              showProgressBar(true);
              return dataManager.getSomething();
            }
          }).repeat().retry().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(new Subscriber<Something>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Something something) {
              // Do something
              showProgressBar(false);
            }
          });
```

I want to set visibility of my `ProgressBar` to `VISIBLE` when the call to the server is being made using `dataManager.getSomething()` and hide it after getting the results. Hiding works perfect but where should I call my `showProgressBar(true)` method to make it visible again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in many ways:
Add `donOnNext()` after the interval.
add `doOnSubscribe()` at the `dataManager.getSomething()`
also putting `showProgressBar(true)` at the `flatMap()` operator should also do the trick.

You just need to make sure to it will happen on the `mainThread()` as your changing the UI, you can achieve it with the `observerOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` operator before your operator, just don't forget to change it back afterwards if you need it on a different thread.
Actually, In this case, assuming you creating this observable in main thread, you will call the `showProgressBar(true)` at main thread, as in default the notifications will happen at the thread created the `Observable`, that means that the `dataManager.getSomething()` will also happen at main thread, so you should add `subscribeOn()` to a different thread.

Comment: Thank you. Its crystal clear now. I was making a mistake of not observing it on main thread.